# Dataset with optional addition to where statement

Tags: c#, beginner, .net, winforms, .net-datatable

I am trying to generate a dataset from a query that has a `where` statement. If the user passes a value additional things need to be added to the `where` statement. Is this the best way to go about this?

```
class TableAdapters
{
    public class FindScriptByTargetVDN
    {
        public static DataSet Fill(SqlConnection connection, string parameter)
        {
            string conditional = string.Empty;
            if (parameter.Length > 0)
            {
                conditional = "and svce.PeripheralNumber= " + parameter + " ";
            }
            string query = "select svce.PeripheralNumber AS Service, " 
                + "ms.EnterpriseName AS [Script Name], "
                + "p.EnterpriseName AS Peripheral, " 
                + "sg.PeripheralNumber AS [Skill Mapping], " 
                + "s.Version AS [Latest Version], "
                + "s.DateTime AS Created, " 
                + "s.Author " 
                + "from Script_Cross_Reference scr " 
                + "LEFT OUTER JOIN Script s on s.ScriptID = scr.ScriptID " 
                + "LEFT OUTER JOIN Master_Script ms on s.MasterScriptID = ms.MasterScriptID "
                + "LEFT OUTER JOIN Service svce on svce.SkillTargetID = scr.ForeignKey " 
                + "LEFT OUTER JOIN Peripheral p on svce.PeripheralID = p.PeripheralID " 
                + "LEFT OUTER JOIN Service_Member sm on svce.SkillTargetID = sm.ServiceSkillTargetID " 
                + "LEFT OUTER JOIN Skill_Group sg on sg.SkillTargetID = sm.SkillGroupSkillTargetID " 
                + "where s.Version = ms.CurrentVersion and scr.TargetType = 1 "
                + conditional
                + "order by svce.PeripheralNumber, ms.EnterpriseName, p.EnterpriseName";
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            dataSet.Tables.Add(new DataTable());
            adapter.Fill(dataSet.Tables[0]);
            return dataSet;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example of the call:

```
this.FindScriptsDataGrid.DataSource = TableAdapters.FindScriptByTargetVDN.Fill(connection, this.ValueTextBox.Text).Tables[0];
```

The connection is defined before the call. The reason for the some what round about method is the user has the option of defining what server they want to run this query on before they run it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This:

> ```
> + "where s.Version = ms.CurrentVersion and scr.TargetType = 1 "
> + conditional
> + "order by svce.PeripheralNumber, ms.EnterpriseName, p.EnterpriseName";
> ```

Is **poison**.

`conditional` came from a string concatenation that involves a `parameter` string that the method cannot trust:

> ```
> conditional = "and svce.PeripheralNumber= " + parameter.ToString() + " ";
> ```

..Uh, the `ToString()` call is superfluous here, `parameter` is already a string! ;)

Looking at the code in your other question, this is where the `parameter` came from:

> ```
> string value = this.ValueTextBox.Text;
> ```

**That** is what you shouldn't be doing: concatenating user input into an SQL statement is asking for trouble, whether it's a web or a desktop application doesn't matter, *SQL Injection* is SQL injection. Not to mention that you just put the calling code in charge of knowing the types for all columns that might be used, whether or not the values should be enclosed in single quotes, etc.

You need to use a *parameterized query* instead.

Comment: Lol yeah the `ToString()` got put in there when I was trying something else with the type of `parameter`, I removed it from my other post guess I didn't catch it here.  As far as everything else I'd love to hear your thoughts on my comment on JohnP's answer.

Comment: to make it work I had to add `adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", (parameter.ToString().Length == 0) ? DBNull.Value : parameter);` Safe or not? oh and converted parameter type to  `object`.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like a reasonable approach. It's similar to one that I've used when building a query completely from an XML file, except I used parameters rather than adding in the string.

```
selectString = string.Format("{0} WHERE {1}='{2}' {3};",
                selectString,
                dateColumn,
                dateSelected.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                additionalCommandsAfterWhereStatement);
```

Comment: the problem with using parameters in this instance is if no parameter is passed I need to not include it in my where statement at all. If I simply put `and svce.PeripheralNumber= @value` directly into the query and the user doesn't pass a value it will either error out or not return anything.

Comment: @aaronmallen give it `and svce.PeripheralNumber = ISNULL(@value, svce.PeripheralNumber)` instead, and pass NULL to ignore the parameter ;)

Comment: @Mat'sMug LOL DUH god and I actually know SQL

Comment: This is also susceptible to SQL injection!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the BEST way to do this is to use LINQ. Build the query in a modern language, and let the runtime automatically convert it safely to SQL using LINQ-To-SQL. It automatically takes care of putting the user-supplied data into the query safely.

Please check out http://www.linqpad.net/WhyLINQBeatsSQL.aspx