# Populating DataGrids

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-datatable

I'm building an in house query tool.  The main form has a drop down which allows the user to select how they want to find scripts, and a drop down for what server they want to run the query on. There is also a text box to allow the user to populate a specific value which can be left blank.  I think I did pretty well here. This is my first desktop WinForms app.

**What Happens When The Query Is Run**

```
private void QueryButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection connection = GetSqlConnection();
    string value = this.ValueTextBox.Text;
    TableAdapters.FindScript dataSource = new TableAdapters.FindScript();

    switch (this.FindByComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString())
    {
        case "Find Scripts By Target VDN":
            this.FindScriptsDataGrid.DataSource = dataSource.FillByTargetVDN(connection, value).Tables[0];
            break;
        case "Find Scripts By Skill Group":
            this.FindScriptsDataGrid.DataSource = dataSource.FillBySkillGroup(connection, value).Tables[0];
            break;
        case "Find Scripts By Translation Route Pool":
            this.FindScriptsDataGrid.DataSource = dataSource.FillByTranslationRoutePool(connection, value).Tables[0];
            break;
        case "Find Scripts By Name":
            this.FindScriptsDataGrid.DataSource = dataSource.FillByName(connection, value).Tables[0];
            break;
        case "Find Scripts By Label":
            this.FindScriptsDataGrid.DataSource = dataSource.FillByLabel(connection, value).Tables[0];
            break;
    }

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.FindScriptsDataGrid.Rows)
    {
        row.HeaderCell.Value = (row.Index + 1).ToString();
    }
}

// SERVER NAMES CENSORED IN THIS POST FOR SECURITY
private SqlConnection GetSqlConnection()
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
    switch (this.ServerComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString())
    {
        case "SERVER1":
            connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["csS01"].ConnectionString;
            break;
        case "SERVER2":
            connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["csS02"].ConnectionString;
            break;
    }
    return connection;
}
```

**The Queries Being Called**

```
class TableAdapters
{
    public class FindScript
    {
        string conditional = string.Empty;
        string query = string.Empty;

        DataSet Fill(SqlConnection connection, string query)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            dataSet.Tables.Add(new DataTable());
            adapter.Fill(dataSet.Tables[0]);
            return dataSet;
        }

        public DataSet FillByTargetVDN(SqlConnection connection, string parameter)
        {
            if (parameter.Length > 0)
            {
                conditional = "AND svce.PeripheralNumber= " + parameter + " ";
            }
            query = "SELECT svce.PeripheralNumber AS Service, "
                + "ms.EnterpriseName AS [Script Name], "
                + "p.EnterpriseName AS Peripheral, " 
                + "sg.PeripheralNumber AS [Skill Mapping], " 
                + "s.Version AS [Latest Version], "
                + "s.DateTime AS Created, " 
                + "s.Author " 
                + "FROM Script_Cross_Reference scr "
                + "LEFT OUTER JOIN Script s ON s.ScriptID = scr.ScriptID "
                + "LEFT OUTER JOIN Master_Script ms ON s.MasterScriptID = ms.MasterScriptID "
                + "LEFT OUTER JOIN Service svce ON svce.SkillTargetID = scr.ForeignKey "
                + "LEFT OUTER JOIN Peripheral p ON svce.PeripheralID = p.PeripheralID "
                + "LEFT OUTER JOIN Service_Member sm ON svce.SkillTargetID = sm.ServiceSkillTargetID " 
                + "LEFT OUTER JOIN Skill_Group sg ON sg.SkillTargetID = sm.SkillGroupSkillTargetID " 
                + "WHERE s.Version = ms.CurrentVersion AND scr.TargetType = 1 "
                + conditional
                + "ORDER BY svce.PeripheralNumber, ms.EnterpriseName, p.EnterpriseName";
            return Fill(connection, query);
        }

        public DataSet FillBySkillGroup(SqlConnection connection, string parameter)
        {
            if (parameter.Length > 0)
            {
                conditional = "AND sg.PeripheralNumber = " + parameter + " ";
            }
            query = "SELECT DISTINCT(sg.PeripheralNumber) AS Skill, " 
                + "ms.EnterpriseName AS [Script Name], " 
                + "s.Version AS [Latest Version], " 
                + "s.DateTime AS Created, " 
                + "s.Author " 
                + "FROM Script_Cross_Reference scr "
                + "LEFT OUTER JOIN Script s ON s.ScriptID = scr.ScriptID "
                + "LEFT OUTER JOIN Master_Script ms ON s.MasterScriptID = ms.MasterScriptID "
                + "LEFT OUTER JOIN Skill_Group sg ON sg.SkillTargetID = scr.ForeignKey " 
                + "WHERE s.Version = ms.CurrentVersion AND scr.TargetType = 2 "
                + conditional 
                + "ORDER BY sg.PeripheralNumber, ms.EnterpriseName";
            return Fill(connection, query);
        }

        public DataSet FillByTranslationRoutePool(SqlConnection connection, string parameter)
        {
            if (parameter.Length > 0)
            {
                conditional = "AND (tr.EnterpriseName like ('" + parameter + "') "
                    + "OR tr.EnterpriseName like ('" + parameter.ToUpper() + "') "
                    + "OR tr.EnterpriseName like ('" + parameter.ToLower() + "')) ";
            }
            query = "SELECT DISTINCT(tr.EnterpriseName) AS Translation_Route, " 
                + "ms.EnterpriseName AS [Script Name], " 
                + "s.Version AS [Latest Version], " 
                + "s.DateTime AS Created, " 
                + "s.Author " 
                + "FROM Script_Cross_Reference scr " 
                + "LEFT OUTER JOIN Script s ON s.ScriptID = scr.ScriptID " 
                + "LEFT OUTER JOIN Master_Script ms ON s.MasterScriptID = ms.MasterScriptID " 
                + "LEFT OUTER JOIN Translation_Route tr ON scr.ForeignKey = tr.SkillTargetID " 
                + "WHERE s.Version = ms.CurrentVersion AND scr.TargetType = 4 "
                + conditional 
                + "ORDER BY tr.EnterpriseName, ms.EnterpriseName";
            return Fill(connection, query);
        }

        public DataSet FillByName(SqlConnection connection, string parameter)
        {
            if (parameter.Length > 0)
            {
                conditional = "AND (ms.EnterpriseName LIKE ('" + parameter + "') "
                    + "OR ms.EnterpriseName LIKE ('" + parameter.ToUpper() + "') "
                    + "OR ms.EnterpriseName LIKE ('" + parameter.ToLower() + "')) ";
            }
            query = "SELECT ms.EnterpriseName AS [Script Name], "
                + "s.Author, "
                + "s.Version, "
                + "s.Valid, "
                + "s.DateTime AS Created "
                + "FROM Script s "
                + "LEFT OUTER JOIN Master_Script ms ON s.MasterScriptID = ms.MasterScriptID "
                + "WHERE s.Version = ms.CurrentVersion "
                + conditional
                + "ORDER BY ms.EnterpriseName";
            return Fill(connection, query);
        }

        public DataSet FillByLabel(SqlConnection connection, string parameter)
        {
            if (parameter.Length > 0)
            {
                conditional = "AND l.Label='" + parameter + "' ";
            }
            query = "SELECT DISTINCT l.Label AS Label, "
                + "ms.EnterpriseName AS [Script Name], "
                + "s.Version AS [Latest Version], "
                + "s.DateTime AS Created, "
                + "s.Author "
                + "FROM Script_Cross_Reference scr "
                + "LEFT OUTER JOIN Script s ON s.ScriptID = scr.ScriptID "
                + "LEFT OUTER JOIN Master_Script ms ON s.MasterScriptID = ms.MasterScriptID "
                + "LEFT OUTER JOIN Label l ON l.LabelID = scr.ForeignKey "
                + "WHERE s.Version = ms.CurrentVersion AND scr.TargetType = 19 "
                + conditional
                + "ORDER BY l.Label, ms.EnterpriseName";
            return Fill(connection, query);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I already have some concerns about the whole `conditional` thing in the `TableAdapters` class which I address [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/55893/dataset-with-optional-addition-to-where-statement).  Other than that are there other areas of improvement that you could point out to me?

Comment: I always cringe a little bit when I see raw SQL being concatenated. Your code becomes ripe for SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @GregBurghardt when I'm working on web based applications I utilize MVC and usually write in LINQ, however this is an intranet winform desktop app so I'm not to concerned with SQL injection attacks.  I actually wrote this app as an MVC web app at one point but we had to pull it because of server loads.  I could never translate these queries into LINQ for some reason they never returned the correct result sets.

Comment: Still, it feels like there should be a safe way to generate SQL queries based on strings and variable substitutions in C#. Maybe I just haven't seen it yet.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I'm curious if the loss in readability would be worth the extra security in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- I assume it's your style to refer to class members using "`this.`". That's not the usual way to do things but it is acceptable.
- It also seems to be your style to capitalize the names of the UI elements. Again, not the usual style but not horrible (it does confuse the syntax coloration here though).
- You really need to separate the UI and the business logic. The way things stand now, it would be impossible to drive the program via an API or a batch process. Especially notable since that's usually the best way to test it.
- I don't believe it's ideal for `conditional` to be a class member of `FindScript`. There's no reason it needs to persist.
- And I'm pretty sure all of the `FindScript` class could get replaced by a `Dictionary<String,String>`, maybe with some `"{0}"` in there so you can use `String.Format()`.
- That big `switch` statement in `QueryButton_Click()` could be refactored into a dictionary.

  For instance:

  ```
  private static TableAdapters.FindScript dataSource = new TableAdapters.FindScript();

  private static readonly Dictionary<String, Func<SqlConnection,String,DataSet>> switchReplacement = new Dictionary()
  {
      {"Find Scripts By Target VDN", dataSource.FillByTargetVDN},
      {"Find Scripts By Skill Group", dataSource.FillBySkillGroup},
      {"Find Scripts By Translation Route Pool", dataSource.FillByTranslationRoutePool},
      {"Find Scripts By Name", dataSource.FillByName},
      {"Find Scripts By Label", dataSource.FillByLabel}
  };
  ```

  And then in the function, you can avoid repeating yourself:

  ```
  SqlConnection connection = GetSqlConnection();
  string value = this.ValueTextBox.Text;
  this.FindScriptsDataGrid.DataSource = switchReplacement[this.FindByComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString()](connection, value).Tables[0];
  ```

  Similarly, the `switch` in `GetSqlConnection()` could be a `Dictionary<String,String>`, to avoid duplicating code.

Comment: Big help here. I renamed my UI variables wasn't sure if I should count those as local or not. Also got rid of `this` that was actually auto generated by Visual Studios for the most part, never use `this` when working with MVC web apps. As the post states I'm already aware of the issue with `conditional` and it's been remedied. I was completely unaware of the Dictionary type and its awesome. Thanks!

Comment: quick question though... I had added `if (!isNumber) { MessageBox.Show("Error Message"); break; }` logic to two of the case statements in my first big switch statement because in two of the options the value needed to be type int.  How can I now add back that functionality? If you could Answer [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56009/error-handling-when-using-dictionary)