# Error Handling When Using Dictionary

Tags: c#, beginner, winforms, hash-map, error-handling

I have set up a `Dictionary` that calls on a class to fill a `DataGridView` via SQL statements.  The problem is in two (out of 5) instances the value passed HAS to be an integer, but the value comes from a textbox so it is being passed as string.  Before I set these Dictionaries up I was just using a switch statement that can be seen [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/55906/populating-datagrids).  In my switch statement I simply added:

```
int n;
bool isNumber = int.TryParse(textBox.Text, out n);

if (!isNumber)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Input must be an integer");
  break;
}
```

to the two cases that needed the value to be an integer type.

Any idea on how I can add error handling to this? Preferably a message box that just says "value needs to be an integer".

```
    private void findScriptsQueryButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
        string value = this.valueTextBox.Text;
        connection.ConnectionString = GetSqlConnection[serverComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString()];
        findScriptsDataGrid.DataSource = GetDataSource[findByComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString()](connection, value).Tables[0];
    }
    private static TableAdapters.FindScript dataSource = new TableAdapters.FindScript();
    private static readonly Dictionary<String, Func<SqlConnection, String, DataSet>> GetDataSource = new Dictionary<String, Func<SqlConnection, String, DataSet>>()
    {
        {"Target VDN", dataSource.FillByTargetVDN},
        {"Skill Group", dataSource.FillBySkillGroup},
        {"Translation Route Pool", dataSource.FillByTranslationRoutePool},
        {"Name", dataSource.FillByName},
        {"Label", dataSource.FillByLabel}
    };

    private static readonly Dictionary<String, String> GetSqlConnection = new Dictionary<String, String>()
    {
        {"SERVER01", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["csS01"].ConnectionString},
        {"SERVER02", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["csS02"].ConnectionString}
    };
```

Comment: Clarification on the text box: Does it have to be a text box? Or can you make it a different type of input?

Comment: In this case the text box will be the most efficient solution.  It's used to pass a parameter to a query which can literally be hundreds of thousands of possible strings or integers.

Comment: If it can be hundreds of thousands, then how are you restricting it in only 2 of 5 instances?

Comment: "Target VDN" and "Skill Group" are the only two queries in the dictionary that REQUIRE an integer value.

Comment: Take a look at the [ErrorProvider class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). And the [StackOverflow errorprovider tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/errorprovider)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your data structure include a validator (this should probably be a `Predicate<String>`); most of the predicates will just return true, but the two that require integers will have a nontrivial validator that checks for integer.

So I guess the type should be `Dictionary<String, Tuple<Func<SqlConnection, String, DataSet>>,Predicate<String>>`

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested, so cannot verify about errors but you could try something like this -

1. Create validator functions for validating input -

   ```
   public bool DummyValidator(string input)
   {

       return true;
   }

   public bool ValidateIntegerInput(string input)
   {
       int n;
       bool isNumber = int.TryParse(input, out n);

       if (!isNumber)
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Input must be an integer");\
           return false;
       }
       return true;
   }
   ```
2. Create dictionary to hold them -

   ```
   private static readonly Dictionary<String, Func<String, Boolean>> GetValidator = new Dictionary<String, Func<String, Boolean>>()
   {
       {"Target VDN", dataSource.ValidateIntegerInput},
       {"Skill Group", dataSource.ValidateIntegerInput},
       {"Translation Route Pool", dataSource.DummyValidator},
       {"Name", dataSource.DummyValidator},
       {"Label", dataSource.DummyValidator}
   };
   ```
3. Then validate before calling methods -

   ```
   SqlConnection connection = GetSqlConnection();
   string value = this.ValueTextBox.Text;

   if (GetValidator[this.FindByComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString()](textBox.Text)){

       this.FindScriptsDataGrid.DataSource = switchReplacement[this.FindByComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString()](connection, value).Tables[0];

   }
   ```

You can map other validators accordingly.